# How to display the last used learning rate after an epoch

Tags: keras

I have tried several methods to display the learning rate of a model effectively used at the last epoch in Keras.

Some research has shown it was possible to change the learning rate using callbacks, or to display the learning rate with a custom metric.
But the displayed learning rate was always the ORIGINAL learning rate, whatever method I tried.

Some answers imply re-calculates how much the rate should be based on the formula. But what I want is simply to get the learning rate which was used for backpropagation, without calculating it based on the algorithm.

Here is some code I used:

```python
callback_list = []
metric_list = ['accuracy']

# Add checkpoints to save weights in case the test set acc improved
#...

if show_learn_param:
    learn_param = Callback_show_learn_param()
    callback_list.append(learn_param)

    # Add metric if needed
    def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
        def lr(y_true, y_pred):
            return optimizer.lr #K.eval(optimizer.lr)
        return lr

    lr_metric = get_lr_metric(optimizer)
    metric_list.append(lr_metric)
```

Here is the definition of the callback:

```python
class Callback_show_learn_param(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = self.model.optimizer.lr
        decay = self.model.optimizer.decay
        iterations = self.model.optimizer.iterations
        lr_with_decay = lr / (1. + decay * K.cast(iterations, K.dtype(decay)))

        # Beta values
        beta_1=self.model.optimizer.beta_1
        beta_2=self.model.optimizer.beta_2
        print("lr", K.eval(lr), "decay", K.eval(decay), "lr_with_decay", K.eval(lr_with_decay),
              "beta_1", K.eval(beta_1), "beta_2", K.eval(beta_2))
```

Basically, the displayed values are constant and do not change. It makes sense for beta values and decay. The shown learning rate seems to be the initial one. For the learning rate, I could not find a way to display this simple value: effective learning rate really used.

There is BTW an easier way to display this initial learning rate:

```python
import keras.backend as K
print(K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `K.get_value` to obtain the learning rate. Have a look at [LearningRateScheduler](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/08c873669f39b37743014db99fcd2d308f8ea5ea/keras/callbacks.py#L623) and how that callback obtains the learning rate from the model. In your case you should be able to print the learning rate:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
  lr = float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
  print("Learning rate:", lr)
```